# Refilling a chest with "special" item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command:

```
/summon FallingSand ~1 ~ ~ {TileID:54,Time:0.9,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:stained_glass,Slot:1,Count:1}]}}
```

I want to add this item command in replace of the `stained_glass`:

```
/give @a minecraft:stained_glass 4 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}
```

So, in the chest there will be stained glass color yellow, that can only be placed on an iron block in Adventure mode. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The `tag` compound holds item data that is not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, or `Slot` tags. The `Damage` tag will state the color of the glass.

You should also **not** be using the `TileID` tag because it is deprecated. Use `Block` instead, which holds the string name of the block. The `Time` tag is an integer, not a double, so you cannot use decimals.

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block ~1 ~ ~ {Block:"minecraft:chest",Time:1,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:4,Slot:1,Count:1,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}}]}}
```